# Improved query statements using a lot of count cases when

Tags: mariadb

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN a = apple THEN 1 END) as '1',
            COUNT(CASE WHEN a = orange THEN 1 END) as '2',
            COUNT(CASE WHEN a = mango THEN 1 END) as '3',
            COUNT(CASE WHEN a = melon THEN 1 END) as '4',
            COUNT(CASE WHEN a = grape THEN 1 END) as '5',
            COUNT(CASE WHEN a = lemon THEN 1 END) as '6', 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN a = watermelon THEN 1 END) as '7',
```

I have a separate category, but I am counting values that are not grouped as count case when. It has such poor performance that I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Don't spam tag.  Pick the database you are using

Comment: I revised it after seeing your comment.

Comment: Take a look at pivoting: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pivoting-in-mariadb/

Comment: I'll refer to it and follow it

Comment: What are orange, melon etc. Columns in the same table?